# Error on connecting to RabbitMQ using TLS

Tags: .net, ssl, openssl, rabbitmq

We recently started doing stuff with RabbitMQ, and now we are trying to use TLS from a .NET application. We are using Erlang OTP 19.0. We followed [this guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html) to generate the CA, client and server certificates using OpenSSL, and we configured on RabbitMQ accordingly. The only difference is that we generated the CA request with the following openssl command:

```
openssl req -x509 -config openssl.cnf -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -out cacert.pem -outform PEM -subj /CN=$(hostname)/ -nodes
```

The difference is that the documentation says `CN=MyTestCA`, while we use `CN=$(hostname)`. However, this does not change the error we're having.

Since we're using .NET, we also join the certificate and the key using the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out keycert.p12 -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -passout pass:somePassword
```

Before testing the certificate in our .NET application, we try to use `s_client` to connect with RabbitMQ, and then we send 8 random bytes, which causes the server to reply with "AMQP", and then the connection closes. This behavior is documented [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html). So far, so good. Time to do some real tests.

We are using the official .NET client for RabbitMQ (RabbitMQ.Client), but we were able to reproduce the problem with this code:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("server_ip", server_port);
var cert = new X509Certificate2("keycert.p12", "somePassword");
SslStream ssl = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, ValidateServerCertificate);

//fails here with "The message received was unexpected or badly formatted"
ssl.AuthenticateAsClient("servername", new X509CertificateCollection { cert },
      System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls, true);
```

Both this code and RabbitMQ.Client fails with "The message received was unexpected or badly formatted". We checked the logs on RabbitMQ, but it just says "handshake_failure".

We need some advice. We have done everything correctly, to the best of our knowledge. But obviously something is missing.

The weirdest thing is that this is not the first time we perform those steps. We have done it successfully some weeks ago, but now something is clearly off.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. All the steps in the troubleshooting guide work using the pem files, but when using our client with the .p12 file, it breaks. No idea what is happening. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution. We just changed our server and everything works now. For the guy who edited my tags: OpenSSL is the right tag, not HTTPS.

Comment: yeah, I have it working on Windows Server 2016. Trying the same steps on Windows Server 2012 R2 results in failure. No idea.

Comment: So, for what it's worth, my Windows Server 2012 was running Erlang 19.1. I updated it to 19.2 and it started working (I had 19.2 on my 2016 server unknowingly).